# Create a new LocalDateTime from a LocalDateTime and a LocalTime

Tags: java, jodatime

Given a date-time and a time,

```
    LocalDateTime rightDateWrongTime = new LocalDateTime("2017-03-02T15:23:00.000");
    LocalTime rightTime = new LocalTime("17:30:00");
```

I can combine them like so:

```
    LocalDateTime rightDateRightTime = rightDateWrongTime.withTime(
        rightTime.getHourOfDay(), rightTime.getMinuteOfHour(), 
        rightTime.getSecondOfMinute(), rightTime.getMillisOfSecond());
```

It feels like there should be a more convenient method. Something like this:

```
    LocalDateTime rightDateRightTime = rightDateWrongTime.withTime(rightTime);
```

But I can't find anything. Does a similar method exist?

Comment: I think you have done the best. In Java-8, there is [a more convenient way](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster-) similar to what you like to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
LocalDateTime rightDateRightTime = rightDateWrongTime.withFields(rightTime);
```

It worked for me (I'm using joda 2.2 - not sure when `withFields` method was introduced)